How to debug Powershell Core script in Visual Studio Code that require admin
After searching at internet I still could not find an answer on how to configure Visual Studio Code to debug Powershell script that require elevated (Administrator) rights for it ?  I started the VSCode itself as admin but the error stay the same - I don't have enough access rights to use those CmdLets
For example Powershell script:
#Requires -PSEdition Core
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

<#
.SYNOPSIS
  This script must be run with elevated user (Administrator)
#>

Import-Module IISAdministration;

$iisManager = Get-IISServerManager
...
...

error is:
$iisManager = Get-IISServerManager
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Filename: redirection.config Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions 


I found a workaround: Configure Visual Studio Code to debug the script by 'attaching to host process' like this:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "PowerShell Attach to Host Process",
            "type": "PowerShell",
            "request": "attach"
        },
...
...

then start an elevated Powershell prompt and run the script. Add a Read-Host somewhere in the script to allow for debugger to attach.
While script waiting on Read-Host attach to it from Visual Studio Code. Voila - now you debugging Powershell script that demand Administrative rights.
P.S. It doesn't not matter if you started VSCode as admin or not
